# Is $R=\{(a,b)\in \Bbb N\times \Bbb N\,:\,(a - b)$ is an odd number $ \}$ an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

$R \subset \Bbb N \times \Bbb N$

Is this an equivalence relation?

$R=\{(a,b)\in \Bbb N\times \Bbb N\,:\,(a - b)$ is an odd number $ \}$

I say it is not because $(a, a)$ is always $0$ which is considered to be an even number.

Comment: No! $1\sim 2$ and $2\sim 3$ but $1\not\sim 3$ (not transitive). Also $1\not\sim 1$ (not reflexive).

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct. It's not transitive, either.

Comment: Note that $(a, a)$ is just an ordered pair; it is neither odd nor even. But $(a, a) \in R$ exactly when $a - a = 0$ is odd, which indeed never happens. So you have the right idea, but you should only say whether $(a, a)$ is in $R$ or not, not that it has (or does not have) properties that integers have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an equivalence relation because it fails to be reflexive as you noticed: $(a, a)$ is not in $R$ since $a-a = 0$ is even. Furthemore, it is not transitive since, for example $(2, 1) \in R$ and $(1,4) \in R$  but $(2,4) \not\in R$ since $2-4 = -2$.